# Getting the row values of the listview by just simply clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there anybody can give me the exact code on how to get the row values
of the listview when it is clicked. I don't want to put my listview control
with buttons like update, or delete buttons. All I want is just a plain listview
control with displayed data and when you click any rows, it will display on my
textboxes.I have already done this in my winform app and I want to use it also in
my asp.net app. I'm not sure what eventhandler I can use in asp.net to get the values
of the listview control by clicking the row whether if its `ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged` or `ListView1_ItemCommand`
because in winform app you can even use directly the `ListView1_Click()` eventhandler by just setting its properties to fullrowselect
and mousehover. I want my listview in asp.net acts exactly that way in which before you click the row it will hover the mouse
with highlighted full row select.I just followed the format of my codes in my winform app using the code below but not sure
if that is right because it doesn't do anything.Here's my code below. Please advise. Thanks.

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox1.Text = ListView1.Items[0].ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = ListView1.Items[1].ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = ListView1.Items[2].ToString();
    TextBox4.Text = ListView1.Items[3].ToString();
    TextBox5.Text = ListView1.Items[4].ToString();
    TextBox6.Text = ListView1.Items[5].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yes. I want to get the selected rows from the listview and display it in my textboxes when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox1.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems[0].ExtractValues(values);
    TextBox2.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems[1].ExtractValues(values);

}
```

Try this code.......

Comment: I don't think there's an extension for SelectedItems in listview for asp.net. You might be referring to winform app I guess.

Comment: It is the listview of telerik